# How to count the occurrence of record in field2 of a table based on field1 in progress openedge 4 gl?

Tags: field, progress-4gl, openedge

I have a table with two fields.

I need to count occurence of data of field2 based on field1 .
Like a(field1) - x(field2) - 1(occurrence of x for a )  , a - y - 2 , b-z-1 for all a  b c d

Comment: I know what all of the words mean and I thought I understood your question right up until the word "Like".  You lost me there.  Perhaps you could show some sample data to help illustrate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I think he's describing the output he wants - not a mathematical formula which is how I first read it. Like the Progress equivalent of "SELECT field1 || ' - ' || field2 || ' - ' || count(*) FROM table GROUP BY field1, field2".

Comment: Its sometimes easier to understand the problem if you use real names instead of "field1", "field2" etc. b - z - 1 makes it very schematic. For example: Income - tax - school_fee at least means something.

Comment: @Jensd Solved the problem using break by and by as you suggested .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem :

```
DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
FOR EACH ttPTdetails NO-LOCK BREAK BY ttPTdetails.sentdate BY stat :

     i = i + 1.
    IF LAST-OF(stat) THEN DO:
        DISPLAY  ttPTdetails.sentdate  (ttPTdetails.stat ) i.
        i = 0.
    END.    
END.
```